# Accessing Mule flowVars/Variable from a Java method

Tags: java, mule

I have created a Mule flow which determines whether or not to download a group of files via SFTP, provided they are all present.

I determine this using a Java method which reads the contents of a folder and then returns either `true` or `false`.

The structure of the Mule flow looks like this:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean class="com.test.FileCheck" name="invokeFileChecks"> 
</spring:bean>
</spring:beans>


<flow name="check-files" processingStrategy="synchronous">
<set-variable variableName="allFilesPresent" value="False" doc:name="Variable - all files present boolean"/>

        <invoke object-ref="invokeFileChecks" 
                method="checkFiles" 
                doc:name="Invoke folder scan" 
                methodArguments="#[flowVars.sftpHost], #[flowVars.sftpPort], #[flowVars.sftpUserName], #[flowVars.sftpPassword], #[flowVars.sftpRequestedFiles]"/>
        <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
```

The Java method looks like this:

```
public boolean checkFiles(String hostname, int port, String username, String password, String fileList){        
    boolean filesPresentTrueOrFalse;

//logic to list folder contents of SFTP:
//If all files are present, return true, otherwise false.

return filesPresentTrueOrFalse;
}
```

How can I assign `allFilesPresent` the value of `filesPresentTrueOrFalse`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the invoke in an enricher. This way the result will go to the target var and not overwrite the payload. It will also keep your java decoupled from mule internals:

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars.allFilesPresent]">
            <invoke object-ref="invokeFileChecks" 
                    method="checkFiles" 
                    doc:name="Invoke folder scan" 
                    methodArguments="#[flowVars.sftpHost], #[flowVars.sftpPort], #[flowVars.sftpUserName], #[flowVars.sftpPassword], #[flowVars.sftpRequestedFiles]"/>
</enricher>
```

Enricher Can only have one processor so anytime thing else needed in there wrap in a processor-chain or a flow and use flow-ref.

Answer (score 0):

Mule variables can be accessed via `setProperty`/`getProperty` methods from the [MuleMessage](https://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current/apidocs/org/mule/api/MuleMessage.html) class.

An instance of `MuleMessage` can be obtained from `MuleEventContext` via `getMessage` method. The event context itself gets injected by implementing method `onCall` of [Callable](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/lifecycle/Callable.html) interface.

So, start with implementing the `Callable` interface in you bean.